# Change Passwod API using Django Custom user model and serializer

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-custom-user

I have a Django application hwere I have extended the User model and created a custom user model for registration/login, now I want to implement a Change Password API which will be used in Android/IOS app development. I would get parameters as:

`user_id, old_password, new_password`

Using these paramters and custom user model and serializer is there any way I could achieve this.

I have tried a sample example for this, but it failed.

Custom Model:

```
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = UserManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True)
    user_android_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_fcm_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_social_flag = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_fb_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_android_app_version = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

User Manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, name, phone_no, created_at, user_android_id, user_fcm_token,
                    user_social_flag, user_fb_id, user_android_app_version, password=None):
        cache.clear()
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            phone_no=phone_no,
            created_at=created_at,
            user_android_id=user_android_id,
            user_fcm_token=user_fcm_token,
            user_social_flag=user_social_flag,
            user_fb_id=user_fb_id,
            user_android_app_version=user_android_app_version,
            name=name,
        )
        user.is_admin = False
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, name, created_at, phone_no, user_android_id, user_fcm_token,
                         user_social_flag, user_fb_id, user_android_app_version, password):
        cache.clear()
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            # password=password,
            created_at=created_at,
            phone_no=phone_no,
            user_android_id=user_android_id,
            user_fcm_token=user_fcm_token,
            user_social_flag=user_social_flag,
            user_fb_id=user_fb_id,
            user_android_app_version=user_android_app_version,
            name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = False
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        cache.clear()
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            # password=password,
            # phone_no=phone_no,
            # created_at=created_at,
            # user_android_id=user_android_id,
            # user_fcm_token=user_fcm_token,
            # user_social_flag=user_social_flag,
            # user_fb_id=user_fb_id,
            # user_android_app_version=user_android_app_version,
            # name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = False
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Custom User Serializer:

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)
    password1 = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    phone_no = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    user_android_id = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    user_fcm_token = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    user_social_flag = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    user_fb_id = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    user_android_app_version = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    # created_at = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d", input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d', 'iso-8601'])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'name', 'phone_no', 'user_android_id', 'user_fcm_token',
                  'user_social_flag', 'user_fb_id', 'user_android_app_version')


    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()

        return {
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'phone_no': self.validated_data.get('phone_no', ''),
            'name': self.validated_data.get('name', ''),
            'user_android_id': self.validated_data.get('user_android_id', ''),
            'user_fcm_token': self.validated_data.get('user_fcm_token', ''),
            'user_social_flag': self.validated_data.get('user_social_flag', ''),
            'user_fb_id': self.validated_data.get('user_fb_id', ''),
            'user_android_app_version': self.validated_data.get('user_android_app_version', ''),

        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

ChangePassword API :

```
class CustomChangePasswordView(APIView):
    """
        User Change Password API
    """
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        u_id = data.get('user_id')
        old_password = data.get('user_old_password')
        new_password = data.get('user_new_password')

        user = User.objects.get(id=u_id)

        if user.password != old_password:
            return Response({"msg":"Invalid Old Password"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            user.set_password(new_password)
            return Response({"msg":"Change successfull!"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Error Response I get:

```
{
"msg": "Invalid Old Password"
}
```

What am I missing?

Is there another better way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update in  the `CustomChangePasswordView` code like this:

```
if user.check_password(old_password):
     user.set_password(new_password)
     user.save()
     return Response({"msg":"Change successfull!"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
     return Response({"msg":"Invalid Old Password"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

You can check the documentation on check password in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password).

Comment: This also go in else part and returns "Invalid Old Password"

Comment: in that case, please check if you are getting right password in `old_password` variable. (maybe via `print(old_password)`)

Comment: Yes, correct, the problem was with the parameter name. Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing a problem here when the user login with social account, and then password is to blank. Once the password in db is blank and I try update using above method, the password didn't get updated. Why?

Comment: you need to call `user.save()` to store the password. Sorry, I missed that earlier. Please see my updated answer